# Python kivy: FloatLayout not centering

Tags: python, kivy

This is the code I used in the kivy file, it should position but it's not Idk if I did a mistake but here:

```
<MyGrid>:

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba:(65/255,42/255,84/255,1) 

        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    animeweb: animeweb
    animename: animename

    FloatLayout:
        width: 500
        height: 250
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5 } 
        
        canvas.before:
            Color:
          
                rgba:(96/255,94/255,94/255,1) 
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
```

Comment: Post a minimal runnable example, and explain exactly what's wrong. I don't know what "not centering" means, what do you expect it to do that it doesn't, and why do you expect that?

Comment: Add more details

Comment: Note that your `height` and `width` for the `FloatLayout` will have no effect without also having `size_hint: None, None`.